# How do I set the project default Maximum Bytes Billed in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

In the BigQuery UI, if I click Show Options there is a field called Maximum Bytes Billed - which is an awesome way to make sure you don't fat finger an expensive query.  When you don't enter a value in that field it says "project default".  How do I set that project default?  I can't find it anywhere.

Also, how does the project default work?  Is it a hard cap that nobody can go over, or if someone enters a higher value in that field can they override the default? Does it apply to all queries from any source or only from the BigQuery UI?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got official confirmation from Google that this is not possible.

Comment: There still seems to be no option to set the default value. You can only change the quota for the query usage per day or per user and day.