# Google BigQuery set limit on query size using estimates

Tags: google-bigquery, size, limit

Google `BigQuery` has a dry-run feature by which we can get an estimate of the  total query size before running it.
Is there some hack/mechanism on the `BigQuery` by which we could set up an upper limit on the allowed size of queries, and automatically reject any queries that exceed that size?

This would be useful, so as to avoid making any queries accidentally that might possibly exceed the set limit (on `WEB UI`, `COMMAND-LINE` and `API`).

Answer (score 7):

You can limit the number of bytes billed for a query using the maximum bytes billed setting. When you set maximum bytes billed, if the query will read bytes beyond the limit, the query fails without incurring a charge.

If a query fails because of the maximum bytes billed setting, an error like the following is returned:

> Error: Query exceeded limit for bytes billed: 1000000. 10485760 or
>   higher required.

In the BigQuery web UI, enter an integer in the Maximum Bytes Billed field in the query options.

[image]

In the CLI, use bq query command with the --maximum_bytes_billed flag.

> bq --location=US query --maximum_bytes_billed=1000000
>   --use_legacy_sql=false "SELECT word FROM `bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare`"

In the API, set the [maximumBytesBilled](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/list#jobs.configuration.query.maximumBytesBilled) property.

See more in [BigQuery Best Practices: Controlling Costs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-costs#limit_query_costs_by_restricting_the_number_of_bytes_billed)

Comment: Great! But I wanted it to be set there by default for the project, and not having to do that manually every time I try to query. Is it possible? Can I be able to set it for multiple users too? Thank you for your time!

Comment: @ShivamTripathi AFAIK is not possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50063742/how-do-i-set-the-project-default-maximum-bytes-billed-in-bigquery you can submit a feature request here:  https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/559654

Comment: The feature request from 2019 was not acted upon and is marked as obsolete in 2022: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140991565.